# Show element on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to show `input text` field on `radio button` selection in vanilla JavaScript.

What am I missing?

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const size = form.elements["size"];
const total = form.elements["total"];

total.style.display = "none";

for (var i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
  if (size[i].checked) {
    total.style.setProperty("display", "inherit");
  } else {
    total.style.setProperty("display", "none");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose Size</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="six">6-inch</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="eight">8-inch</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="twelve">12-inch</label>
</fieldset>

<input type="text" name="total" readonly>
</form>
```

*I’m aware that there are similar questions previously asked on Stack Overflow, but all of them are in jQuery.*

Comment: Can you explain what you want the `input` to show when different radio buttons are clicked? Are you trying to only show the input when the last button is selected, or what?

Comment: This is part of a bigger form that will calculate the sum of values of many fieldsets and then display the total in a `readonly` `input` field. I would like to unhide the `input text` field after any of the radio buttons are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const size = form.elements.size;
const total = form.elements.total;

total.style.display = "none";

for (var i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
  size[i].onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      total.style.setProperty("display", "inherit");
      total.value = this.value;
    } else {
      total.style.setProperty("display", "none");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose Size</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="6" id="six" required>6-inch</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="8" id="eight">8-inch</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="12" id="twelve">12-inch</label>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="text" name="total" readonly>
</form>
```

Check this on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iNullPointer/Lo68cr04/24/)

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener for the `click` event of each of the radio buttons.

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose Size</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="six" required>6-inch</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="eight">8-inch</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="twelve">12-inch</label>
</fieldset>

<input type="text" name="total" readonly>
</form>
<script>
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const total = form.elements["total"];
const radios = form.querySelectorAll("input[name=size]");
total.style.display = "none";
radios.forEach(i=>{
i.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if(this.checked){
  total.style.setProperty("display", "inherit");
  total.value = this.id;//sets value of readonly input to the id of the selected radio button
} 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I posted my full code if you’d like to take a look: [Simplifying and Improving Form Calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/201965/177275)

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation on the `fieldset` - whenever it observes a bubbled `change` event, you know that one of the `<input>`s has been selected, so you can then set the `style` of the `total` input field. Use `{ once: true }` so that the listener only gets triggered once:

```js
const total = document.querySelector('input[name="total"]');
document.querySelector('fieldset').addEventListener('change', () => {
  total.style.display = "inherit";
}, { once: true });
```

```css
input[name="total"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose Size</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="six">6-inch</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="eight">8-inch</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="twelve">12-inch</label>
</fieldset>

<input type="text" name="total" readonly>
</form>
```

Comment: I posted my full code if you’d like to take a look: [Simplifying and Improving Form Calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/201965/177275)